# How can I reference second level collections in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Currently my Firebase database is using the following structure

*Users*

- User 1 Data
- User 2 Data...

However I have created a new collection inside of the "users" collection called "products" which will store product details that users have uploaded on the application.

How can I ensure that once a user uploads a new product, it is only uploaded into their 'User X data' dataset, inside the respective "products" collection. The code I currently have only uploads the data into the "users" collection, with no reference of the users who added the product as required. I have shown the structure of my Firebase database below for reference.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    db.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let userId = data["uid"] as! String
                    if userId == user?.uid {
              
                        db.collection("users").document("products").setData(["productNameField":firstName, "productURLField":lastName,"productPriceField":ebayName, "productDescriptionField":etsyName, "productTimeRemainingField":email])
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How would I go about updating my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

db.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let userId = data["uid"] as! String
                if userId == user?.uid {              
                document.reference.collection("products").addDocument(["productNameField":firstName, "productURLField":lastName,"productPriceField":ebayName, "productDescriptionField":etsyName, "productTimeRemainingField":email])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So here `document` is the `DocumentSnapshot` that you're looping over, so `document.reference` gives you the reference to that specific document, and `document.reference.collection("products")` then points to the `products subcollection for that specific document.

Answer (score 1):

You're wastefully looping over the entire list of users to FIND the user document needed.  Simplify, simplify - use the user.uid as the Id of the user document!! (i.e. when you create the user document, save it as

```
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({whatever})
```

...then it's trivial to access as...

```
 let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
 
  db
  .collection("users")
  .doc(user.uid)
  .collection("products")
  .setData([
    "productNameField":firstName,
    "productURLField":lastName,
    "productPriceField":ebayName,
    "productDescriptionField":etsyName,
    "productTimeRemainingField":email
  ]);
```

If there is another reason to keep the docID and the uid separate (not shown here), then use a query to get the SPECIFIC document with the uid, rather than downloading ALL of them

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    db
    .collection("users")
    .where(field: "uid", opStr:"==", value: user.uid)
    .getDocuments( { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        } else { //the query should only return the one document, but queries always return an array
            snapshot
            .documents[0]
            .ref()
            .document("products")
            .setData([
              "productNameField":firstName,
              "productURLField":lastName,
              "productPriceField":ebayName,
              "productDescriptionField":etsyName,
              "productTimeRemainingField":email
              ])
         }
      }
...etc...
```

I don't generally use Swift, so the where clause may require different formatting, but the idea is GET ONLY THE DOCUMENT YOU NEED.  Your security rules should only be allowing this, anyway.